# Horizontal scrollbar missing in SharePoint Online Modern List

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I am working with a SharePoint Online site collection that has the Modern experience. If a view has too many columns to display on the page, previous versions of SharePoint add a horizontal scrollbar (like you would expect to see in ANY website that has additional content). But there is only a vertical scrollbar. Is this a feature? Is this a setting I can turn on or off?

UPDATE: Based on suggestions from @Julie_MSFT, made the following tests:

- Only on Chrome on customer laptop.
- Happens on multiple SharePoint sites.
- I see scrollbar in Edge on customer laptop.
- I see scrollbar in Chrome on my desktop.
- Coworker sees scrollbar.
- Created new list, still don't see scrollbar in Chrome on customer
  laptop.

On a whim, I tried "Expand Content". Under expand content, I can see a scrollbar. When I collapse content, the scrollbar goes away. So, I have a workaround. But I am still curious as to the cause.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. However, my browser (edge) is up to date. Makes pages with lists in it virtually unusable. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My client manages software updates for their environment, including Chrome. I can't just download the latest version. That is typical for many organizations. They are months, if not a year, behind in deploying updates. I am made to upgrade Chrome every other week now.

Once they pushed a certain update, this problem resolved itself. I can now see the horizontal scrollbar as well as the totals, which apparently is at the bottom of the table instead of the top (thanks, Microsoft, I liked it better at the top). Mystery solved.

Answer (score 1):

Per my test, I could not reproduce your issue:

[image]

To narrow down the issue, please check as following:

1. If you switch to other browsers, will the same issue happen?
2. Do your colleagues have the same problem?
3. If you create a new list,will the same problem happen?

Comment: Only on Chrome on customer laptop. Happens on multiple SharePoint sites. I see scrollbar in Edge on customer laptop. I see scrollbar in Chrome on my desktop. Coworker sees scrollbar. Created new list, still don't see scrollbar in Chrome on customer laptop.

Comment: Please ask customer use the latest Chrome , clear browser cache to compare the result,

Comment: My issue, not customer's. I am on version 74, my client controls the upgrades of Chrome. I see here at home I have version 93, so clearly they are behind. That is probably the issue.

Comment: If you find any response helpful to you, please mark it as an answer.